# how to use aggregate function bit_xor in postgres

Tags: postgresql

manual:

> bit_xor
> Computes the bitwise exclusive OR of all non-null input
> values. Can be useful as a checksum for an unordered set of values.

I don't understand the explanation.

```
with cte as (
select 1::bit(4)
union
select 3::bit(4)
union
select 7::bit(4)
union
select 5::bit(4)
)
select *,bit_xor(bit) over()  from cte;
```

return

```
 bit  | bit_xor
------+---------
 0001 | 0000
 0011 | 0000
 0101 | 0000
 0111 | 0000
(4 rows)


with cte as (
select 1::bit(4)
union
select 3::bit(4)
union
select 7::bit(4)
)
select *,bit_xor(bit) over()  from cte;
```

return

```
 bit  | bit_xor
------+---------
 0001 | 0101
 0011 | 0101
 0111 | 0101
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bit_xor should work like this for each digit of the input rows :

With 2 input rows :

```
1 xor 1 = 0
0 xor 1 = 1
1 xor 0 = 1
0 xor 0 = 0
```

With 3 input rows :

```
1 xor (1 xor 1) = 1
1 xor (0 xor 1) = 0
1 xor (1 xor 0) = 0
1 xor (0 xor 0) = 1
0 xor (1 xor 1) = 0
0 xor (0 xor 1) = 1
0 xor (1 xor 0) = 1
0 xor (0 xor 0) = 0
```

With 4 input rows :

```
1 xor (1 xor (1 xor 1)) = 0
1 xor (1 xor (0 xor 1)) = 1
1 xor (1 xor (1 xor 0)) = 1
1 xor (1 xor (0 xor 0)) = 0
1 xor (0 xor (1 xor 1)) = 1
1 xor (0 xor (0 xor 1)) = 0
1 xor (0 xor (1 xor 0)) = 0
1 xor (0 xor (0 xor 0)) = 1
0 xor (1 xor (1 xor 1)) = 1
0 xor (1 xor (0 xor 1)) = 0
0 xor (1 xor (1 xor 0)) = 0
0 xor (1 xor (0 xor 0)) = 1
0 xor (0 xor (1 xor 1)) = 0
0 xor (0 xor (0 xor 1)) = 1
0 xor (0 xor (1 xor 0)) = 1
0 xor (0 xor (0 xor 0)) = 0
```

etc ...